# Ability to use SSH Key / PEM for web authentication in lieu of password protection?

Tags: security, apache-2.4, ssh-keys

I've been trying to figure out a way to lock down our dev site even more, and the idea came up that instead of using IP centric + Password protection, using something more akin to a PEM key, like I would use for ssh'ing into a server. I'm curious if this is a viable thing, and how it would be set up. I've looked into the Apache AuthType docs and seen that it support multiple things aside from Basic, such as Digest and Form, I'm curious if I can leverage either of these, or possibly something else in order to have our servers ports 80 and 443 only viewable on presentation of a cert?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are asking for is [possible](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ssl/ssl_howto.html#allclients). However, do to the lack of a `starttls`/`stls` command in `http`, it is only available to `https`. Non-certificate ssh-keys will not work for this purpose.

A client will need their certificate (and private key) installed in their browser.
The sever will need to include the following directives in addition to other standard ones for a https listener.

```
SSLVerifyClient require
SSLVerifyDepth 1
SSLCACertificateFile path/to/a/trusted/CA.crt
```

Answer (score 1):

If your site uses SSL, there's the option of using client certificates to authorize an user.

The method works this way:

1. You configure Apache to use client certificate authentication
2. Create a CA to generate and sign the certifications
3. Generate and sign certifications for all your users
4. Configure the directory to use the SSLVerifyClient directive

There's a very good and detailed guide [here](https://www.scriptjunkie.us/2013/11/adding-easy-ssl-client-authentication-to-any-webapp/).